# Why this ln expresion equals this one

Tags: logarithms, conditional-probability

Working with these expressions, in terms of math operations how you determine that both
are the same when you have.
x=3/4 and the following expression
-1/ln(1-(3/4)) == 1/ln(4)
[Ln expresion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRubR.png)

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, you just have to use the properties of the logarithm

$\frac{-1}{\ln(1-\frac{3}{4})}=\frac{-1}{\ln(1/4)}=\frac{-1}{\underbrace{\ln(1)}_{=0}-\ln(4)}=\frac{-1}{-\ln(4)}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.